# Show that the projection is linear

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I want to show the following:

Let $U$ be a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H$, then the projection $P_U$ is linear.

My attempt:
For $U$ closed subspace of $H$, the projection $P_U$ is defined using the best approximation $||P_Ux-x||:=min_{u \in U} ||u-x||$.
I don't see that this definition is useful in this case.

$(*)$ But I thought maybe I could use the fact that $P_Ux$ is the unique element in $U$ such that $<x-P_Ux,u>=0$ for every $u \in U$.
I.e, maybe I could take advantage of the linearity of the inner product.
Then $P_U(x+y)$ is the unique element such that
$<x+y-P_U(x+y),u>=0$ for all $u \in U$

This means, I need to show that $<x+y-P_Ux-P_Uy,u>=0$.
By the properties of the inner product we get
$<x+y-P_Ux-P_Uy,u>=<x-P_Ux,u>+<y-P_Uy,u>=0$

Next, $P_U(\lambda x)$ is the unique element such that
$<\lambda x-P_U(\lambda x),u>=0$.

Thus I need to show that $<\lambda x- \lambda P_Ux,u>=0$ which is obvious since $<\lambda x- \lambda P_Ux,u>=\lambda <x-P_Ux,u>=0$.

Question:
Is this proof correct, resp. is the approach the right one.
I tried to use $(*)$ since it uniquely characterizes $P_Ux$. But I am kind of unsure, since I have the feeling that I would need to use the definition instead.

Comment: It might be simpler to work with a dual characterisation, that is, $u$ is the nearest point to $x$ **iff** $(x-u) \bot U$. Then show linearity in the usual way, $\lambda u$ is the nearest point to $\lambda x$ and $u_1+u_2$ is the nearest point to $x_1+x_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct and your approach is the easiest one. Its main ingredient is the fact that $H$ is the direct sum of $U$ and its orthogonal complement $U^\perp=\{v\in H\mid\forall u\in U,\;\langle v,u\rangle=0\}$. More generally, you can prove similarly that for *any* vector space $W$ over some field $K$ and any subspaces $U,V$ such that
$$W=U\oplus V,$$
the projection
$$P:W\to U$$
characterized by
$$\forall x\in W,\;x-P(x)\in V$$
is linear:

- for every $x,y\in W$, $P(x)+P(y)=P(x+y)$ since $(x+y)-(P(x)+P(y))=(x-P(x))+(y-P(y))\in V+V\subseteq V$;
- for every $x\in W$ and $\lambda\in K$, $\lambda P(x)=P(\lambda x)$ since $(\lambda x)-\lambda P(x)=\lambda(x-P(x))\in\lambda V\subseteq V$.